# Pm2 is unable to find start script

Tags: next.js, pm2

I am currently experiencing the issue where I am trying to start my next.js application with pm2 but it keeps failing.

I run the following commands ...

```
npm run build

pm2 start npm --name "next" -- start
```

in the root directory of the nextjs project ( the one that has `/node_modules`, `/pages`, etc. )

However, when I run the command I get the following error

```
[PM2][ERROR] Script not found: C:\Users\...\frontend\start
```

I see people talking about using an `ecosystem.config.js` file to specify the directory of the script. However, I can't seem to find the directory of the `next start` script.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Everywhere I look it tells me to run the pm2 command I ran above and any solution to the problem of not finding the script recommends the *ecosystem.config.js* file. However, I am unable to find the correct path the *next start* script.

Comment: I am running this on a `Windows Server 2019`

Comment: Did you ever fix this? Same issue on linux machine...

Comment: Unfortunately no and I can't seem to find anywhere that even tries to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party but my NextJs + PM2 + Windows kinda work after multiple tries.

My folder structure:

```
PM2App
======
-apps (where NextJS and other apps reside)
 -nextapp
  -node_modules
  -package.json
  ...
 -otherapp
 ...
-ecosystem.config.js
```

ecosystem.config.js is like this:

```
module.exports = {
    apps : [{
      name: 'NextJS Apps',
      script: 'node_modules/next/dist/bin/next',
      args: 'start -p 3000', //running on port 3000
      cwd: "./apps/nextapp",
      instances: 1,
      watch: false,
      env: {
          ...
      },
    }]
  };
```

Start pm2 with:

```
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js
@
pm2 start
```

Comment: not sure if this is relevant but might as well add this in 

1) my pm2app is at C:\

2) added path for nodejs

3) running in cluster mode for pm2

Answer (score 1):

For my NEXT.js app I use the following ecosystem.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    apps : [{
        name   : "next",
        script : "npm",
        args: "run dev",
        watch: ["."],
        watch_delay: 1000,
        ignore_watch: ["node_modules"]
    }]
}
```

It runs with the command `pm2 restart ecosystem.config.js` at root where the above config file is located. Would automatically restart as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. In the root directory of a NextJS application, running `pm2 start npm -- start` produces the following error:

```
[PM2][ERROR] Script not found: C:\app\start
```

And I also couldn't find any real help on why `pm2 start npm -- start` wasn't working for me.

If you're just after the location of the next scripts to put into an ecosystem file for pm2, Konstable Piksel had that correct: `./node_modules/next/dist/bin/next`

If, like me, you're dumb and need explicit instructions, here's what worked for me.

I needed a Windows 10 kiosk running a NextJS application offline and standalone.

What I had:
Intel NUC with Windows 10 v21H2
Node v18.16.0 installed
A NextJS application bootstrapped with `create-next-app` on 14 Feb, 2023
pm2 from https://github.com/jessety/pm2-installer installed and working

Clone or download the application repo

In the root directory of the NextJS app (`C:\app` in my case), install dependencies and create a production build
`C:\app> npm install`
`C:\app> npm run build`

Generate a template file by running
`C:\app> pm2 init simple`
This will create an ecosystem.config.js file that looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [{
    name: "app1",
    script: "./app.js"
  }]
}
```

The name field is what pm2 will use to refer to the application and can be anything. The script field will need to be edited and an args field added.

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [{
    name: "app1",
    script: "node_modules/next/dist/bin/next",
    args: "start"
  }]
}
```

(You can also run any other next script here. This is equivalent to running `npm run start` from the command line. E.g., you can change the args field to "dev" and it would be equivalent to running `npm run dev` from the command line.)

My file tree now looks like this:

```
C
└─app
   └─ .next
   └─ node_modules
   └─ pages
   └─ public
   └─ styles
   |  .gitignore
   |  additional.d.ts
   |  ecosystem.config.js
   |  next-env.d.ts
   |  next.config.js
   |  package-lock.json
   |  package.json
   |  README.md
   |  tsconfig.json
```

After that, the usual pm2 commands will start the application
`C:\app> pm2 start ecosystem.config.js`
`C:\app> pm2 save`